# Which is the most frequent term for “detergent”?

Tags: word-choice, word

According to Pleco, there are very many terms for “detergent”: 去垢剂, 洗涤剂, 洗洁剂, 洗涤灵, 清洁剂, 除垢剂.

Which is the most frequent term for “detergent”?

Comment: Detergent for what (clothes, dishes, kitchen greases, car washes..)? I think 清洁剂 is the general term for cleaning chemicals.

Comment: @r13 detergent in general

Comment: I think 去垢剂 and 除垢剂 are more for certain applications (usually involving heavy duty), and 洗涤灵 sounds like a brand name for a commercial product. Depending on the region, either one of the rest can be the most dominant term in certain locals.

Comment: @r13 Why wouldn’t you write an answer with this content? I would be pleased to accept it

Comment: I appreciate your acceptance of my comments and wish them to be helpful to you, but don't be surprised if someone corrects you in future encounters :) It changes with time and locality.

Answer (score 2):

Common words are:

洗洁精: for washing dishes
洗衣粉, 洗衣液: for washing clothes